# Wrapping an async function and maintain async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am using the [node request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request/) which is setup as follows:

```
request(object,function(data));
```

The function is a callback with the response data in it. I want to feed in a predefined set of objects, and wrap the request function in another function like so:

```
var quickReq(object,func){
  request(object,func);
}

quickReq({
  "method":"GET",
  "url":"http://someapi.com",
}
,function(error, response, data) {
  res.send(data);
});
```

Is this valid async code?

Comment: It's valid, but why do you need to wrap a `request` into a 'twin' object - i.e., without any additional functionality in this wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this valid async code?

Yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but the first parameter to `request`'s callback is an error code, and the *second* parameter is the returned content (assuming it succeeded).